# Rails - Mongoid querying on a association field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have models like this

```
class TestOne
  field value

  belongs_to test_two ,:class_name => 'TestTwo'
end

class TestTwo
  field name
  field start_time, :type => DateTime

  has_many TestOne

end

I am running a query of range like this

result = TestOne.where(:value => "some_value" , 'test_two.start_time' => (Time.now-1.days..Time.now + 1.days).last
```

The result set of above query is empty even though there exists several record in TestOne that fulfills the criteria. Can any one suggest what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A MongoDB query can only access one collection at a time, there are no joins here.

When you say:

```
'test_two.start_time' => (...)
```

MongoDB will be looking for a field in `test_ones` named `test_two` that is a hash (or array of hashes) with a `start_time` field inside that hash. You don't have that structure so your query doesn't find anything.

Also, you can query any MongoDB collection for any fields you like and MongoDB won't complain; documents within a collection have no set per-collection structure: any document in any collection can contain any fields with any types. That's why you can use this query without anyone complaining.

You need to do the query in two steps (i.e. do the join by hand):

```
test_two_ids = TestTwo.where(:start_time => (Time.now-1.days..Time.now + 1.days)).pluck(:id)
result = TestOne.where(:value => "some_value" , :test_two_id.in => test_two_ids).last
```

There are a couple alternatives that are more work:

1. Keep a copy of `db.test_twos.start_time` in the `db.test_ones` collection (i.e. precompute the JOIN by denormalizing). This would require you to update the copies every time `db.test_twos.start_time` changes and you'd have to periodically sanity check all the copies and fix the broken ones because they will become out of sync.
2. If you don't need `TestTwo` to exist on its own then embed `TestTwo` inside `TestOne`. This would leave you with a hash field called `test_two` inside your `db.test_ones` collection and your original query would work. However, you wouldn't be able to access `TestTwo` on its own anymore, you'd have to go through `TestOne`.

Comment: use `pluck(:id)` instead of `.only(:id).map(&:id)`

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris You're right, `pluck` is better here.